# Find a folder or file by name

Tags: box-api

I would like to know if there is a way in V2 api to  find a file or folder by its name . In search can we  mention such filters to look up for item type and item name or use wild card characters or regex.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 3):

There is a search endpoint in the V2 API that you can do a GET /search?query= on.  Docs are at http://developers.box.com/docs/#search-searching-a-users-account

It doesn't support filters for item type, nor wildcards, nor regex.  It uses a starts-with search algorithm, so there is some ability to work with that to find your files or folders by name.  We may support some of those ideas in the future.

Comment: The docs you linked to are obsolete. The new location for what you are searching for is: https://box-content.readme.io/reference#searching-for-content